# Remove all gradients from SVG

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, linear-gradients, inkscape

I have a SVG file with a few objects it. They all have a linear gradient applied to them on top of their fill colour. I would like to clear all these gradients so that they are all one solid colour.
I have found online many methods to "clean" a svg i.e. remove all unused gradients, but here I would like to remove all gradients whether they are used or not.

Is there a method? (I have looked into inkscape and into the XML without finding anything obvious)

Comment: Have you tried anything like just doing a selectAll on linearGradient and removing it ?

Comment: SVG is also XML, have you thought about an XSLT filter to remove all gradient nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was actually quite easy. Select all objects and in Fill and Stroke set them to Fill.
Then use File > Clean up document to clean the unused gradients.

Comment: Sorry, I tried File->Clean up document, but no linearGradients were removed.

Answer (score 0):

All gradients should be defined in the `<defs>` section.
delete all "gradient" tags here or remove the entire `<defs>` section.

Comment: That doesn't help with the "replace with a solid color" aspect of OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I did a very basic approach with Python:

1. Search for linear gradients within a svg file using the built-in xml.etree.ElementTree library using findall() with XPath expressions.
2. Extract a solid color by selecting the first attribute "stop-color".
3. Extract the "id" attribute to search the tree where the corresponding gradient was used.
4. Search the tree and overwrite the attribute "fill" by the previously obtained solid-color.

(Currently, it only searches for linear gradients and does only take the first color from it as a template. The script could be extendend by other gradient types and a method that extracts multiple colors to build an average color as template.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Remove gradients from svg file and replace them by solid color
# First open the svg file to be modified
tree = ET.parse("Graphs-Screenshot.svg")
root = tree.getroot()

# Search for the linearGradient tag within the svg file
for descendant in root.findall("{*}defs/{*}linearGradient"):
    print(descendant)
    id = descendant.get("id")
    print("id: " + id)

    # Extract the (first) color of the gradient as template
    # for solid color fill.
    # Might be extended to extract average of multiple colors
    color = descendant[0].get("stop-color")
    print("color: " + color)
    print("{*}g/{*}"+id)

    # Replace all gradients with previously extracted solid color
    for gradient in root.iterfind("{*}g/"):
        if gradient.get("fill") == ("url(#"+id+")"):
            print("old gradient:", gradient.get("fill"))
            gradient.set("fill", color)
            print("new solid color:", gradient.get("fill"))
        
# Save the edited svg file
tree.write("newSVG.svg", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Code can also be found here:
https://github.com/DrakeGladiator/SVGGradientRemover

Comment: Actually you are somewhat right. Many "tags" (i.e. parts of the community which focus a tag with a topic) feel that code is self-explaining and sufficient. I think however, that the idea of what the perfect answr is is largely shared. If you see that the most highly upvoted answers you see in your area are code-only, then I am plain wrong for that field. On the other hand, maybe even higher is possible. Whatever, have fund And thanks for taking my comments as constructive.